# How to replicate the unique key (Unique value in a column against a value in another column) against a record at it's multiple occurrences?

Tags: sql, database, validation, database-design

[image]

So I have a table named dragon with 2 columns Pokemon and Power. My result table should look like what is given in the image. How do I do that using SQL? I get a feeling that it is possible using Join. But I am struggling to come up with the right thought process.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is result as view

```
SELECT  
  D.Pokemon, 
  CASE WHEN D.Power IS NOT NULL THEN D.Power ELSE D1.power END
FROM  Dragon D
LEFT JOIN 
 ( 
    SELECT 
      Pokemon, 
      MAX(Power) Power 
    FROM Dragon 
    WHERE Power IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY Pokemon) D1
ON D.Pokemon = D1.Pokemon
```

You can also use similar query to update the existing table like below

```
UPDATE D
SET D.power= D1.power
FROM  Dragon D
    LEFT JOIN 
     ( 
        SELECT 
          Pokemon, 
          MAX(Power) Power 
        FROM Dragon 
        WHERE Power IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY Pokemon) D1
    ON D.Pokemon = D1.Pokemon
    WHERE D.Power IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
select d.*, max(power) over (partition by pokemon) as imputed_power
from dragon d;
```

If you want to actually modify the data, then in Standard SQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
update dragon
    set power = (select max(d2.power) from dragon d2 where d2.pokemon = d.pokemon)
    where power is null;
```